# DbContext does not contain a definition for 'Format' and no extension method 'Format'

Tags: entity-framework, odata

Create a OData client that get reference to a OData Service (using WCF Data Services). This OData Service reference to a project that have a DBContext (I use Code First with Entity Framework). When I update entities, than update OData Service, and OData Service reference on the OData client, I get this error. I don't know what it is. How can I resolve it? Thank you so much.
Image link: http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/1318/4jvp.jpg

Comment: Under which namespace / project is sDevContext?

Comment: I'm guessing sDevContext is a derived class of DataServiceContext? Which version of WCF Data Services is being used on the client? (DataServiceContext.Format was introduced in 5.1)